# Dell P2419H problem with 1920x1080 resolution in 20.04 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, display-resolution

I am using UBUNTU 20.04 LTS and I have an external Dell P2419H 23' Monitor connected to an HP envy 13 through a DP cable. I have the following issue:

On Settings --> Display there is no option for FHD resolution (1920x1080 resolution). The only 16:9 available resolution is the 1600x900 (see picture). How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try a live session of Ubuntu 21.10. I suspect your hardware is too new for a 2 years old release.

Comment: I have the same exact issue, have you managed to fix it?